# Android java.io.File.listFiles() not working properly in Environment.getDataDirectory()

Tags: android, filesystems

I want to read file present on

> Environment.getDataDirectory()

(data directory of android device) but I can't.

Can anybody help me on it.

Here is file code:

```
File aFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), "/");
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/filelist.txt");

public void Process(File aFile) {
    spc_count++;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
        for (int i = 0; i < spc_count; i++)
            spcs += " ";
        if(aFile.isFile()){

            fos.write(aFile.getPath().getBytes());
            fos.write('|');
        }
        else if (aFile.isDirectory()) {

            File[] listOfFiles = aFile.listFiles();
            if(listOfFiles!=null) {
                for (int j = 0; j < listOfFiles.length; j++)
                    Process(listOfFiles[j]);
            } else {
                //System.out.println(spcs + " [ACCESS DENIED]");
            }
        }
        spc_count--;
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Maxim, first up, on SO it's usually best to say precisely how it's not working. Replace `/handle exception` with proper logging and then tell us how it's going wrong. (p.s. on android you typically use `Log.d()` instead of `System.out`). Best,

Comment: Also, I see you've combined two bits of code here into one- could you tell us how `Process` gets called.

Comment: Thanks Tom, It simply called inside a fuction without any return type and having a file type argument.

Comment: Any news from logging yet? For example, you'll be able to confirm is CommonsWare (who's jumped in below) is right by actually logging for the problem. Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you do not have read access to that directory.

Comment: @MaximXion: Have the user run your app as root.

Comment: The data directory is protected, and for a very good reason: it holds *all* of the user's personal data from all apps. This includes settings, contacts, messages, calendar data,... You need a very good reason for your app to justify such access and even then it'll only work properly on rooted devices.