# Android : Is there any alternative to listFile function (Android java.io.File.listFiles())

Tags: android

When I m trying to read file present inside data directory of android by using listFile function. It returns `false`. Can anybody help me on it?

Here is my code:

```
File aFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), "/");
File[] listOfFiles = aFile.listFiles();

if(listOfFiles!=null) {.....}
```

Here it returns `null` every time, even there are file present inside data directory.

Comment: Please do not post two questions about the same thing. You literally [asked about this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18574822/1321716) just half an hour ago.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have read access to that directory. Hence, it will return a `null` list.

Comment: @CommonsWare.. you are just great....awesome..

Comment: But why are you pasting duplicate answers? Though he has already posted same question and you have given same answer before 10 mins...!!! Strange..